# UseSendExecute in ConfigurePublish in MassTransit 5.2.1

Tags: c#, masstransit

In MassTransit 5.2.0 I used the method UseSendExecute inside ConfigurePublish for adding headers to a particular message type:

```cs
    var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((h,cfg) =>
    {
         h.ConfigurePublish(x =>
            x.UseSendExecute<TestMessage>(p => 
            { 
                  p.Headers.Set("x-deduplication-header", p.Message.Day.Ticks);
            }));
    });
```

After upgrading to MassTransit 5.2.1 the method UseSendExecute is not longer available inside ConfigurePublish.

Digging a little inside MassTransit changes I found that the problem happens because MassTransit.IPublishPipeConfigurator no longer implements MassTransit.ISendPipeConfigurator and UseSendExecute is an extension method for ISendPipeConfigurator inside MassTransit.DelegatePipeConfiguratorExtensions.

How can I set the same publish configuration using 5.2.1 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're configuring a publish behavior. The new syntax would be:

```
var bus = BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus((h,cfg) =>
{
    h.ConfigurePublish(pc => pc.AddPipeSpecification(
        new DelegatePipeSpecification<PublishContext<TestMessage>>(p =>
        {
            p.Headers.Set("x-deduplication-header", p.Message.Day.Ticks);
        })));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try to use the method UseExecute as you suggested I get this compile error:
`'IPublishPipeConfigurator' does not contain a definition for 'UseExecute' and the best extension method overload 'DelegateConfigurationExtensions.UseExecute<PublishContext<TestMessage>>(IPipeConfigurator<PublishContext<TestMessage>>, Action<PublishContext<TestMessage>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IPipeConfigurator<PublishContext<TestMessage>>'`

Comment: I did some more tests and the only way to get a successful compilation is removing the type from PublishContext: 
`h.ConfigurePublish(x =>
                   x.UseExecute<PublishContext>...`

But doing this I can't access to the TestMessage to set the header value

Comment: Tried your last suggestion but it didn't work, IPublishPipeConfigurator doest not contain a definition for Message